# How to get td innerHTML per row and then set div css per row based on this value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table as per the below and I want to use `javascript` or `Jquery` to get the value from the middle cell of each row. I then want to see the width of a `div` (`id="myprogres"`) in the last cell to match the percentage that we just got.

My problems that I know of are

- my `td` tags don't have an `id` or anything unique to identify them by. So identifying the 3rd `td` on each row isn't as simple as `getElementById`
- I want to get the value on each row, and then set the corresponding `myprogress` width based upon that value.
- `myprogress` is not a unique `id`, it's the same `id` per row.

This is a simplified version of the table so I appreciate the full `css` isn't there.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hard drive</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>
      <div style="width:100%">
        <div id="myprogress"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Memory</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>
      <div style="width:100%">
        <div id="myprogress"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brain Power</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>
      <div style="width:100%">
        <div id="myprogress"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First find all the divs in 4th td of the table

```
 var divs = $("tr td:nth-child(4) div");
```

> run a loop to set the width of the div and get the value from the 3rd td

```
 for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    $(divs[i]).css({'width': $(divs[i]).parent().prev('td').text() + '%'});
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Just for future reference, I see how we are getting the parent td, then going back one td and retrieving it's value... what if the value we wanted was in a td 2 or 3 tds away (forward or backward) rather than just using previous?

Answer (score 2):

> My `td` tags don't have an `id` or anything unique to identify them by.

This isn't a problem as you can loop over the progress bars directly.

> I want to get the value on each row, and then set the corresponding myprogress width based upon that value.

As above, you can loop over the progress bars and use DOM traversal methods to get the related value from the previous `td` cell to set as the width of the bar. Specifically the  `closest()` and `prev()` methods.

> myprogress is not a unique id, it's the same id per row.

This is invalid HTML and needs to be fixed. Use a `class` instead.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('.myprogress').css('width', function() {
  return $(this).closest('td').prev().text() + '%';
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  width: 25%;
}
.myprogress {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hard drive</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td><div class="myprogress"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Memory</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><div class="myprogress"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brain Power</td>
    <td>Usage</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td><div class="myprogress"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Vanilla JS, you can achieve the result **without jquery**, with the help of [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method..

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const row = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

row.forEach((tr,i) => {
  const width = tr.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-of-type(3)")[0].textContent;
  const progress = tr.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-of-type(4)")[0];
  progress.querySelector('div').style.width = `${width}%`;
})
```

```css
table td {
  width: 10%;
}
#myprogress {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>Hard drive</td>
         <td>Usage</td>
         <td>25</td>
         <td>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div id="myprogress"></div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Memory</td>
         <td>Usage</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div id="myprogress"></div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
<tr>
         <td>Brain Power</td>
         <td>Usage</td>
         <td>75</td>
         <td>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div id="myprogress"></div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```